# Appending Data w/ Bootstrap-table plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, twig, bootstrap-table

On page load, Symfony/Twig take care of providing/rendering the data initially shown in the table which bootstrap-table is applied on.

Users can click to get more records at which point I do:

```
$table = $("#reviewTable");
$table.bootstrapTable('append', data);
```

In this case data is structured as it is in this example: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/methods/append.html BUT I am returning HTML for many of the cells. This sort of works but I lose the table-related styling on the appended rows.  Things aren't centered or spaced correctly because that styling is done at the cell level.

I would prefer to use the AJAX capability that bootstrap-table has built in however I don't want to lose the power that Twig provides since I am using Symfony2 behind the scenes.

Any thoughts from those who have used this (or similar) plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up replacing the Twig template and server-side HTML generation with a JS solution.  Here is what my final code ended up like.

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="tblReviewDetails"
                       data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true"
                       data-ajax="getReviewData" data-side-pagination="server" data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, 250]">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="centerCell" data-field="type" data-sortable="true">Site</th>
                            <th class="centerCell" data-field="rating" id="headRating" data-sortable="true" data-width="100px">Rating</th>
                            <th data-field="content" data-width="50%">Review Content</th>
                            <th data-field="time" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
                            <th class="centerCell" data-field="author" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                            <th data-field="url">Direct Link</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

JS:

```
function getReviewData(params, offset) {

    $.post("/extended-review-monitor/reviews", {"limit": 10, "offset": offset})
        .done(function (data) {
            console.dir(data);

            processedData = transformData(data.data);

            console.log("processed data");
            console.dir(processedData);

            setTimeout(function() {
                params.success({
                    total: data.data[0].total,
                    rows: processedData
                });

            }, 1000);

        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("ajax error");
        });

    console.log("ajax complete");
}

function transformData(data) {

    var transformedArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = {
            id : data[i].id,
            type : getTemplate('type', data[i].type),
            author : data[i].author,
            time : data[i].time,
            rating : getTemplate('rating', data[i].rating),
            content : getTemplate('content', data[i].content),
            url : getTemplate('url', data[i].url)
        };

        console.log("In loop: " + i);
        console.dir(obj);

        transformedArray.push(obj);
    }

    return transformedArray;
}

function getTemplate(key, value) {

    var html = '';

    switch (key) {
        case "type" :
            html = '<img src="/images/social-icons/' + value + '.png" style="height:32px;" title="' + value + '"/>';
            break;
        case "rating" :
            html = getRatingHTML(value);
            break;
        case "content" :
            html = getContentHTML(value);
            break;
        case "url" :
            html = '<a class="viewButton" href="' + value + '" target="_blank">View</a>';
            break;
    }

    return html;
}

function getContentHTML(value) {

    var html = '<div',
        indicator = '';

    if (value.length > 275) {
        html += ' class="block-with-text"';
        indicator += '<div class="over-flow-indicator">[Read more]</div>';
    }

    html += '>' + value + '</div>' + indicator;

    return html;
}

function getRatingHTML(value) {
    var html = '<div class="starContainer" style="min-width: 72px">';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        html += '<span class="gfsStar ';
        if (i <= value) {
            html += 'on';
        }

        html += '"></span>';
    }

    html += "</div>";
    html += '<div class="ratingBadge">' + value + ' / 5</div>';

    return html;
}
```

This approach works great and the styling + event handlers are all preserved.